# android project is slow after encoding mismatch

Tags: android

I have an irritating problem with my android studio project. When i created my project, i got the message there was an encoding mismatch. So, i set it to utf-8.

But after this, android studio (the layout preview) is 'rendering' and loading the whole time and reacts slow when i change my code. Strange is that this is my only project where this happened. My other projects had utf-8 already and there was no mismatch. Also those projects acted normal and i could edit the code in a normal way.

I have the idea i am looking over something very simple, but after my research i don't have a solution.

Do you know why my project is the only project that is slow? Thanks already for your help!

Comment: i'm sorry my other projects have windows-1252 not utf-8